# Defining a globally accessible string in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, string, global-variables

What is the best way to define a globally accessible string?

I see that for integer it's usually like this
#define easy 0

However, how can I emulate that for NSString?
I tried static `NSString *BACKGROUND = @"bg.png";`
While that work, it does give a warning saying the variable is never used. (I have all these in a .h file)

Doing `NSString *const BACKGROUND = @"bg.png";` is even worse since it says duplicate variable when I import the file.

I see that `#define BACKGROUND @"bg.png"` seems to work too.

So I guess what is the difference between when to use `#define`, `const` & `static`

Thanks,
Tee

Comment: Another possibility is to load localized strings from resources. See http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This is the correct way to do it. Make some new blank .h file and .m. In your .h file:

```
extern NSString* const BACKGROUND;
```

In your .m file:

```
NSString* const BACKGROUND = @"bg.png";
```

Comment: It's actually `extern NSString *const`--otherwise, the contents of the string (i.e. `*BACKGROUND`) are marked const rather than the pointer.

Comment: When you say correct answer, what do you mean? Is it better to use extern const than using #define? Is it due to performance

Comment: If you do a define, it basically does a search and replace through your whole code base. If you use a const, it will be a 32/64 bit integer pointing to the string in memory. Much more efficient than having the string allocating memory wherever it is used.

Comment: @Matt Williamson  #define STRING @"888" will replace all occurrences in your source at compile time with @"888" before compiling.  However, I believe the compiler will take all the occurrences of @"888" and just allocate it once and point to it wherever it is used.   I believe the ObjC runtime optimizes that down to one allocation at compile time with the string data embedded in your app data section.

Answer (score 7):

You might want to consider using a [property list](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048-CJBGDEGD) to store your strings.  This lets your code stay flexible for future updates, especially if you add support for localization.