# Defining Global Constants in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a constants.h file that looks something like

```
#ifndef constants_h
#define constants_h

#define MyAdUnitID @"XXXXXXX"
#define GoogleAnalyticsID = @"XXXXX"

#endif
```

and want to reference it throughout my other implementation files. These are just simple string values that I want as NSString instances throughout my program, but can't seem to get it to work.

If there is a better practice to this, please let me know!

Comment: why not just use extern const? try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497088/objective-c-define-vs-const-vs-static

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use extern instead of define.

in .h:

```
extern NSString* SHKFacebookAppID;
```

in .m:

```
NSString* SHKFacebookAppID = @"1234567890";
```